# Derivative of an equation, math

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Would you please help me with the derivative of this equation as my mathematics background is bit weak

```
1) (dxf/dt)=k∆p/(∅[ML+(1-M) xf])


2) (d(xf+ɛ)/dt)=k∆p/(∅[ML+(1-M)(xf+ɛ)])
```

It follows that:

```
3) dɛ/dt=(-k(1-M)∆pɛ)/(∅[ML+(1-M) xf ]^2 )
```

I am not sure how the equation jumped from 1 and 2 to three. Any suggestions how to derive this equation

Comment: the idea is to compute (2) - (1) and the LHS matches, then transform the RHS to show it matches as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT :

$\dfrac{d}{dx}\bigg(f(x)+g(x)\bigg) = \dfrac{d}{dx}f(x)+\dfrac{d}{dx}g(x)$

In your case you take $(2)-(1)$ to get the required equation
;

Comment: By the way, if you tried to solve it, you will find that in there is a missing (1-M)ɛ, Do you know how it disappeared from the final equation?

Comment: @user8670370 take the LCM and expand the numerator, im pretty sure itll cancel out